# Не открывается админка сайта на локалке (wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cms, url

Скачала проект с хостинга на локальную машину(для модернизации), развернула проект, пользовательская часть работает без проблем, но после заполнения формы входа в админку, редиректит на главную страницу сайта, лежащего на хостинге. Сайт работает на WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

> Скачала проект с хостинга на локальную машин
>   ..
>    редиректит на главную страницу сайта, лежащего на хостинг

Туда-сюда тягать ВП-сайты нужно с пом плагиов миграции. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

И лучше не на локальную машину, а на том уже хостинге на др. домене (закрыв к нему доступы из вне).

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в бд таблицу wp_options там есть строки siteurl и home - скорректируйте их для своего локалхоста. Перед выгрузкой на боевой сервер не забудьте изменить значения!

Duplicator понадежнее все-таки будет, чем такие манипуляции

Comment: Эти советы не работают. Угробите сайт. Почитайте здесь на SO мой ответ на вопрос, как правильно перенести WordPress сайт

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220